# Can PyCharm help me to extract a free function from a method?

Tags: python, pycharm, automated-refactoring

I'd like to get from

```
class Sum:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def evaluate(self):
        return self._a + self._b
```

to

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b


class Sum:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def evaluate(self):
        return add(self._a, self._b)
```

i.e., extract from method `evaluate` the expression `self._a + self._b` as a "free function" (a function that isn't a method). Is this possible with PyCharm's automatic refactorings?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this can be done with a single refactoring, but it can be done almost fully automated in 3-4 steps:

1. extract a method with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
2. turn it into a free function ("move method to top-level" in PyCharm lingo) with <kbd>F6</kbd>
3. rename arguments with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
4. (Optional:) move the function to the top of the source file (manually)

The steps in detail:

## First step: extract a method

1. Select the expression or statement(s) to be extracted (here `self._a + self._b`)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

   *or*

   from the context menu of the selection, choose **Refactor** > **Extract** > **Method...**
3. In the dialog window that appears, enter a name for your function (in my example `add`) and click **OK**.

The result will look like this:

```
class Sum:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def evaluate(self):
        return self.add()

    def add(self):
        return self._a + self._b
```

## Second step: turn method into a free function

Now, let's pull the new method out of the class and turn it into a module-level function:

1. Select the newly extracted method or place the cursor anywhere in it (signature or body)
2. Press <kbd>F6</kbd>

   *or*

   from the context menu, choose **Refactor** > **Move...**
3. In "Make Method Top-Level" dialog window that appears, leave the "To" input field as-is (i.e. set to the current module's source file location) and click **Refactor**

The result will look like this:

```
class Sum:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def evaluate(self):
        return add(self._a, self._b)


def add(_a, _b):
    return _a + _b
```

## Third step: rename the arguments

As you can see, the refactoring has correctly replaced the `self` argument with two arguments for the operands. Unfortunately, it has used the `_...` names of the corresponding "hidden" instance members.

1. Select one underscore (`_`) in the function's signature or where the function uses the arguments
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

   *or*

   from the context menu of the selection, choose **Refactor** > **Rename...**
3. In the "Rename" dialog window that appears, the underscore will already be selected, so just press <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or click the **Refactor** button)

Repeat for the other function argument(s).

(In scenarios where you want to choose completely different names, simply place the cursor into the argument name to change without selecting a portion of it. Then the whole name will start out selected in the dialog input field and can be overwritten by typing something new.)

The result will look like this:

```
class Sum:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def evaluate(self):
        return add(self._a, self._b)


def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

## Fourth step (optional): Move the function to the top of the source file

(or where-ever you want to place it)

As you can see, PyCharm placed the new top-level function after the class. I wanted to have it before it. Moving it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> as recommended in [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43471987/674064) didn't work for me in PyCharm 2016.3.2 on GNOME, so I just selected the function, and cut it with <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and pasted it where I want it with <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a direct way of doing what you want, but you can work around it:

1. Select the `self._a + self._b` statement and Right Click > Refactor > Extract > Method, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
2. In the popup window, choose a name for your function (ex. `add`) > OK. This will generate a class function named as given. The process will also refactor the usage to match your case.
3. Select the newly generated function and it contents and by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> hit the <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> buttons to move it where you want it to be in your code. Also as you have it selected and placed in it's final place, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to fix you identation.
4. Change the generated function arguments to match your case: 
   Erase `self`, add `a`, `b`, etc.
    Also erase `self.` everywhere inside the function. You can do this by find and replace: 
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> > type `self.` in the first search bar > leave the second search bar empty and starting by the beginning of your file, click on the <kbd>Replace</kbd> button, until everything seems correct.
5. In your `evaluate` function erase the `self.` that will be generated before the name of your generated function. Also pass the correct arguments to the function (ex. `return add(self.a, self.b)`)

And you are done, it is a bit of work and it is not that much automated, but it will save you some typing time!

*This is tested in PyCharm 2017.1 pro edition*

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, there is still no direct solution, but here is a short workaround:

1. Extract method with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
2. Go to declaration of the new method (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on its name)
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select `Make function from method` (make sure that the cursor is on the method's name)